# Why Java compiler generates weird local vars & stack map frames and how can I use them to reliably determine variable types?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, stack-frame

I'm creating Java byte code instrumentation tool with the help of ASM framework, and need to determine and possibly change the type of local variables of a method. Very quickly I encountered a simple case where variables and stack map nodes look somewhat weird and don't give me enough information about variables being used:

```
public static void test() {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    for (Object i : l) {
        int a = (int)i;
    }
}
```

Gives the following bytecode(from Idea):

```
public static test()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 42 L0
    NEW java/util/ArrayList
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL java/util/ArrayList.<init> ()V
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 43 L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/List.iterator ()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    ASTORE 1
   L2
   FRAME APPEND [java/util/List java/util/Iterator]
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Iterator.hasNext ()Z
    IFEQ L3
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Iterator.next ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    ASTORE 2
   L4
    LINENUMBER 44 L4
    ALOAD 2
    CHECKCAST java/lang/Integer
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue ()I
    ISTORE 3
   L5
    LINENUMBER 45 L5
    GOTO L2
   L3
    LINENUMBER 46 L3
   FRAME CHOP 1
    RETURN
   L6
    LOCALVARIABLE i Ljava/lang/Object; L4 L5 2
    LOCALVARIABLE l Ljava/util/List; L1 L6 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 4
```

As one can see, all 4 explicitly and implicitly defined vars take 1 slot, 4 slots are reserved, but only 2 defined, in strange order (address 2 before address 0) and with a "hole" between them. List iterator is later written to this "hole" with ASTORE 1 without declaring the type of this variable first. Only after this operation stack map frame appears but it is unclear to me why only 2 variables are put into it, because later more than 2 are used. Later, with ISTORE 3, int is written into a variable slot again, without any declaration.

At this point it looks like I need to ignore variable definitions altogether, and infer all types by interpreting the bytecode, running the simulation of JVM stack.

Tried ASM EXPAND_FRAME option, but it is is useless, only changing the type of the single frame node to F_NEW with the rest still seen exactly as before.

Can anybody explain why do I see such a strange code and if I have other options beyond writing my own JVM intepreter?

Conclusion, based on all the answers(please correct me again if I'm wrong):

Variable definitions are only for matching source variable names/types to specific variable slots accessed at specific lines of code, apparently ignored by JVM class verifier and during code execution. Can be absent or don't match the actual bytecode.

Variable slots are treated like another stack, albeit accessed via 32-bit word indices, and it is always possible to overwrite its contents with different temporaries as long as you use matching types of load and store instructions.

Stack frame nodes contain the list of variables allocated from the beginning of the variable frame to the last variable that is going to be loaded in the subsequent code without storing first. This allocation map is expected to be the same regardless of what execution path was taken to reach its label. They also contain similar map for the operand stack as well. Their contents may be specified as increments relative to the preceding stack frame node.

Variables that only exist within linear sequences of code will only appear in the stack frame node if there are variables with longer lifetime allocated at higher slot address.

Comment: Stack frames are only necessary when control flow is merged. Otherwise, the verifier can compute the types in a linear pass, so they are omitted to save space.

Comment: @Antimony Thanks, I understand this, but still puzzled by the incompleteness of the metadata for variable types. If it doesn't always describe all variables referenced in LOAD/STORE opcodes, what's the point?

Comment: The point is to enable debugging and speed up bytecode verification respectively. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you will indeed need to write some kind of interpreter if you want to know the types of stack frame elements at each code location, though [most of this work has already been done](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/?org/objectweb/asm/commons/AnalyzerAdapter.html), but it still isn’t sufficient to restore the source level types of local variables and there is no general solution for that at all.

As said in other answers, attributes like `LocalVariableTable` are truly intended to help restoring the formal declarations of local variables, e.g. when debugging, but only cover variables present in source code (well, actually that’s the compiler’s decision) and are not mandatory. It’s also not guaranteed to be correct, e.g. a bytecode transformation tool might have changed the code without updating these debugging attributes, but the JVM doesn’t care when you’re not debugging.

As also said in other answers, the `StackMapTable` attribute is only meant to help bytecode verification, not to provide formal declarations. It will tell the stack frame state at branch merge points, *as far as necessary for the verification*.

So for linear code sequences without branches, the type of local variables and operand stack entries is only determined by inference, but these inferred types are not guaranteed to match the formally declared types at all.

To illustrate the issue, the following branch-free code sequences produce identical bytecode:

```
CharSequence cs;
cs = "hello";
cs = CharBuffer.allocate(20);
```

```
{
    String s = "hello";
}
{
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(20);
}
```

It’s the compilers decision to reuse the local variable’s slot for variables with disjunct scopes, but all relevant compilers do.

For the verification, only the correctness matters, so when storing a value of type `X` into a local variable slot, followed by reading it and accessing member `Y.someMember`, then `X` must be assignable to `Y`, regardless of whether the local variable’s declared type actually is `Z`, a supertype of `X` but a subtype of `Y`.

In the absence of debugging attributes, you could be tempted to analyze the subsequent use to guess the actual type (I suppose, that is what most decompilers do), e.g. the following code

```
CharSequence cs;
cs = "hello";
cs.charAt(0);
cs = CharBuffer.allocate(20);
cs.charAt(0);
```

contains two `invokeinterface CharSequence.charAt` instructions, indicating that the variable’s actual type likely is `CharSequence` rather than `String` or `CharBuffer`, but the bytecode is still identical to, e.g.

```
{
    String s = "hello";
    ((CharSequence)s).charAt(0);
}
{
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(20);
    ((CharSequence)cb).charAt(0);
}
```

as these type casts only influence the subsequent method invocation, but do not generate bytecode instructions on its own, as these are widening casts.

So it’s not possible to precisely restore the declared types of source level variables from the bytecode in a linear sequence and stackmap frame entries are not helpful either. Their purpose is to help verifying the correctness of the subsequent code (which can be reached through different code paths) and for this, it doesn’t need to declare all existing elements. It only has to declare the elements existing prior to the merge point and being actually used after the merge point. But it depends on the compiler whether (and which of) the entries actually not needed by the verifier are present.

Answer (score 5):

`LocalVariableTable` is for matching variables in the source code to variable slots in the method bytecode. This optional attribute is mostly for debuggers (to print the correct name of a variable).

As you've already answered yourself, in order to infer local variable type or an expression type you have to iterate through the bytecode: either from the method beginning or from the nearest stack map. `StackMapTable` attribute contains the stack maps only at the merge points.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on apangin's answer: You have to consider the purpose of the attributes you are looking at.

`LocalVariableTable` is optional metadata added for debugging purposes. It is what allows a debugger to display the values of local variables to the programmer, including their names and source level types. However, the corollary of this is that the compiler only emits debug information for *source level* variables. Slot 1 is for the iterator implicitly generated by your for loop so there is no sensible debugging information to emit. As for slot 3, that is for your `a` variable. I'm not sure why it isn't added, but it is possible that it is because the scope of the variable ends immediately after it is created. Therefore, the bytecode range for the variable `a` is empty.

As for the `StackMapTable`, stack maps are designed to speed up bytecode verification. The first corollary of this is that it holds only bytecode level type information - i.e. there are no generics or anything like that. The second corollary is that it only holds the information needed to assist the verifier.

Prior to the introduction of stack maps, the verifier potentially did multiple passes through the code. Each time there was a backwards branch in the code, it would have to go back and update the types, which would potentially change further inferred types and so on, so the verifier had to iterate until convergence.

The stack maps are designed to allow the verifier to verify method bytecode in a single pass from top to bottom. Therefore, it requires the types to be specified explicitly wherever there is a jump target. When the bytecode gets to that location, it can just check the currently inferred types against the types in the stack frame instead of having to backtrack all the time and redo things. But there is no need for stack frames in the middle of linear sections of code, since the verifier's inference algorithm works perfectly fine for that.

The last question you had was why only two values are listed in the stack frame. The reason is that to reduce space, stack maps are delta encoded. There are a number of different frame types, and in common cases, you can just list the differences from the previous frame instead of emitting a full frame that lists the types of all the variables and stack operands each time.

There are two stack map frames listed in the bytecode you posted. The first is an `append` frame, which means the operand stack is empty and it has the same locals as the previous frame except with 1-3 additional local variables. In this case, there are two additional locals, with types `List` and `Iterator`. The second frame is a `chop` frame, which means that the operand stack is empty and it has the same locals as the previous frame except that the last 1-3 locals are missing. In this case, one local is chopped off because the iterator is no longer in scope.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate description!